# jest --watch triggered by temp files

Tags: javascript, jestjs, watchman

I'm running Jest 26.4.2 on MacOS Catalina using Emacs as my text editor. When the watcher is running, any time Emacs creates a temp file jest will trigger a run. This leads to many runs triggering that tend to miss the actual file save event.

I'm running jest with `npx jest --watch`

I've tried [various jest configs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration), the one that looked promising, `testPathIgnorePatterns`, did not help.

Emacs creates temp files by making a symlink with the pattern `.#<target file name>` that points to a files that ends with 5 digits. I've tried ignoring all these but it didn't help.

`jest.config.js`:

```
  watchPathIgnorePatterns: ['/[0-9]{5}/', '/#/'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/[0-9]{5}/', '/#/'],
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: ['/[0-9]{5}/', '/#/'],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files created by my editor, Emacs / Spacemacs, are [lock files](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LockFiles). They are created and removed as soon as files are edited, saved or reverted.

I could not get `jest` to ignore them so I configured my Spacemacs TypeScript layer to not create them in TypeScript mode via `(typescript :variables create-lockfiles nil)`.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at a recent jest (26.6.1 in april 2021), the `createHasteMap()` function calls `sane` with an [`ignored`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sane#user-content-sanedir-options) composed from `config.modulePathIgnorePatterns` and `config.watchPathIgnorePatterns` ([src](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/4926564f35fcf78250a884bd93d08fb4c307b9fe/packages/jest-runtime/src/index.ts#L308)). [`watchPathIgnorePatterns`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#watchpathignorepatterns-arraystring) seems appropriate but I'm welcome to counter-advice.

**jest.config.js**

```json
module.exports = {
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: [
    "\\/\\.#"
  ]
}
```

If for some reason, you have `.../.#...` paths in your directory hierarchy that you **don't** want to skip, you can create a more specific pattern using the keyword `<rootDir>`, which will be substituted to point to the root of your project. (If you also have a directory called `<rootDir>`, quit screwin' around.)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you forgot to add a dot and remove the slash at the very end (since it's a file not a folder)? So instead of `/#/` it should be `/.#`? I'm not a regex master, so just created two files

- `.#test.test.js`
- `test.test.js`

and looks like the first one is ignored correctly (`npm t -- --watch`) with my `package.json` config. You can also try playing with a `<rootDir>`, or pass the config file directly using `npm t -- --config jest.config.js`

```js
"jest": {
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
        "<rootDir>/.#",
        "/.#"
    ]
}
```

Comment: thanks @robi24 but that didn't work for me. the files my text editor is creating are 'new' so maybe that has something to do with why I cannot seem to ignore them.